# why caching is not working in this code from gitlab-ci?

Tags: java, angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Given the code below, extracted from my project's .gitlab-ci.xml, I would like to know why the cache is not working.

Notice that there are three stages related to the package_install stage, one for each environment. In each step, a java/maven and an angular project is packaged. Do I need to call the cache or reference the cache within each step? Or is there something else wrong?

```
image: XXX

stages:
  - package_install
  - xxx

  

variables:
  PROJECT_NAME_BACK: contaspublicas-backend
  PROJECT_NAME_FRONT: contaspublicas-frontend



cache:
  
  - key: $PROJECT_NAME_BACK
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/repository/
  - key: $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT
    paths:
      - node_modules



package_install_testes: #Skips testes, pois serão executados na fase de teste
  stage: package_install
  script:
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_BACK
    - mvn -Ptest install -DskipTests=true 
    - cd ..
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT
    - npm ci 
    - ng build --configuration test --base-href .
    - cd dist/contaspublicasng
    - jar cvf contaspublicasng.war .
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.war
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.jar
    - $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT/dist/contaspublicasng/contaspublicasng.war
  except:
    - main
    - homolog



package_install_homolog: #Skips testes, pois serão executados na fase de teste
  stage: package_install
  script:
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_BACK
    - mvn -Phml install -DskipTests=true
    - cd ..
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT
    - npm ci
    - ng build --configuration hml --base-href .
    - cd dist/contaspublicasng
    - jar cvf contaspublicasng.war .
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.war
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.jar
    - $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT/dist/contaspublicasng/contaspublicasng.war
  only:
    - homolog



package_install_main: #Skips testes, pois serão executados na fase de teste
  stage: package_install
  script:
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_BACK
    - mvn versions:set -DremoveSnapshot
    - mvn -Pprod install -DskipTests=true
    - cd ..
    #- echo versao=$(ls starbackend/target/ | grep war | cut -d '-' -f 2 | sed -e 's/\.war$//') >> build.env 
    - echo VERSAO=$(ls $PROJECT_NAME_BACK/target/ | find . -type f -name \*.war | cut -d '-' -f 2 | sed -e 's/\.war$//') >> build.env
    - cd $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT
    - npm ci
    - ng build --configuration prod --base-href .
    - cd dist/contaspublicasng
    - jar cvf contaspublicasng.war .
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.war
    - contaspublicas-backend/target/*.jar
    - $PROJECT_NAME_FRONT/dist/contaspublicasng/contaspublicasng.war
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
  only:
    - main
```

The way it is the cache does not work in the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `maven` to use directory configured there:

```
cache:
  - key: $PROJECT_NAME_BACK
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/repository/
```

smth. like:

```
variables: 
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.m2/repository"
```